# https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/me returning application_not_allowed

Tags: uber-api

Hi we are trying to fetch profile info by calling  https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/me and passing the access token. But evrytime we are getting the following response

{
"code": "application_not_allowed",
"message": "Application not allowed."
}

P.S. We are able to fetch the authorization code and access token in subsequent api calls before calling the final api ( https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/me)